# Polygon coordinates of a country in Python

Tags: python

At the moment I am using a bounding box (with two coordinates) of a country to extract some data in mapillary.

```
list = list(mercantile.tiles(west, south, east, north, 14))
```

The problem is that these bounding boxes do not cover the specific country efficiently, so I always have to cut a part of the country or need to use the adjoining countries which delivers me a lot of data in my extraction process I do not want.
Is there a possibility of using a polygon with more coordinates to better define the specific country in Python?

[image: Something like in the picture on the right.]

Comment: `list = list(...)`. Can you see the problem-potential here?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but it might have a better audience in [gis.se]?

Comment: Python doesn't know anything about polygons, let alone countries. It's probably a good idea to tag the question to match whatever specific library you are using. Providing some more *details or clarity* as per [ask] would be nice too.